# REST API custom endpoint to fetch pages and posts not working

Tags: php, theme-development, rest-api

I'm building a theme from scratch that will use vue.js under the hood. I'm now using the standard wordpress endpoint to fetch pages and posts, I would really create my custom endpoint to pass as a response, a custom set of data instead of the default one provided by the REST API. 
I've already registered a custom endpoint for the menu and it's working fine. I want now to register two more endpoints to get pages and posts, but I'm not able to make the things work. I will get a 404 or a 500 error from the endpoint and I need to fix this. To get evary page or post I'm using the slug, this mean that the `GET` or `POST` requests needs to have that parameters as querystring. I don't know if my code is correct, but I'm not able to get it inside my `functions.php` file. Any help will be appreciated.

functions.php

```
// NB: the code is part of a small class that manage the routes. the register_rest_route function
// is inside a class method and the rest_api_init is called correctly 
   register_rest_route( 'theme/v1', '/pages/', array(
      'method' => 'GET',
      'callback' => array($this, 'get_page_data')
    ));

  public function get_page_data( $request )
  {
    //var_dump( $request );
    $slug = $request->get_params('slug');
    $page = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'page' );  
    $page_meta = get_page_meta( $page->ID ); 
    $images = get_post_gallery_images( $page->ID );

    foreach( $images as $image_url ){
      $attachments_url[] = $image_url;
    }  

    $data = array(
      'ID' =>  $page->ID,
      'title' => get_the_title( $page->ID ),
      'content' => strip_shortcodes($page->post_content),
      'excerpt' => $page->post_excerpt,
      'page_meta' => $page_meta,
      'attached_images' => $attachments_url,
      'featured_image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $page->ID )
    );
    return $data;
  }

// In the vue app js file the url for the request is 
https://mysitedomain.com/wp-json/theme/v1/pages?slug=pageslug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there's a [default endpoint for retrieving pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#list-pages), but I presumed that you intentionally did not use it?

Now the issues with your code:

1. That `$request->get_params()` gets all the parameters and not a single one. So for single parameters, you should use `$request->get_param()`.

   ```php
   $slug = $request->get_params('slug');  // incorrect
   $slug = $request->get_param( 'slug' ); // correct
   ```
2. The error `500` is likely because there's no function named `get_page_meta` in WordPress. Did you mean to use `get_post_meta`?

   ```php
   $page_meta = get_page_meta( $page->ID ); // incorrect
   $page_meta = get_post_meta( $page->ID ); // correct
   // or do you have a custom get_page_meta() function?
   ```
3. As I already mentioned in your other question, the correct array key is `methods` and not `method`. And for the exact same callback (and parameters), you can supply an *array of methods*. (See below examples)
4. I'm guessing you got the error `404` because you tried to make a POST request to your custom endpoint, in which case the error is expected since you haven't added an endpoint for POST requests. So add it, like the examples [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#examples) or see below:

   ```php
   register_rest_route( 'theme/v1', '/pages', array(
       array(
           'methods'  => 'GET',
           'callback' => array( $this, 'get_page_data' ),
       ),
       array(
           'methods'  => 'POST',
           'callback' => array( $this, 'get_page_data' ),
       ),
   ) );

   // or provide an array of methods:
   register_rest_route( 'theme/v1', '/pages', array(
       'methods'  => [ 'GET', 'POST' ],
       'callback' => array( $this, 'get_page_data' ),
   ) );
   ```

Comment: Hi Sally, how are you? thanks for the quick answer. I'm using the default endpoint of wordpress to prototype the vue custom theme I'm creating. I want to switch to a custom endpoint because I want to include only the needed fields I want to render in the DOM. For now I'm having this issue, I will fix the typos in my code and try, I was reading about regex when params are passed, is it needed to make the endpoint works?

Comment: Another thing, I'm using Multi post thumbnails to add more featured images to posts and pages to use them inside the page/post when displayed. I' have a custom rest field added to get the custom metadata fields, can I use the same method to output all the thumbnails ?

Comment: Sorry I deleted my previous comments. And if you actually mean the default Pages routes like `/wp/v2/pages/<id>` (e.g. `/wp/v2/pages/123`), then that `123` (the `id` parameter) is required when retrieving a single Page or updating or deleting/trashing it. And yes, if your REST field is registered for the `page` post type, then it should be available when using the default Pages endpoints.

Comment: ok, thanks. I've played a bit with the code and now I'm able to get all the info I need using the custom endpoints of my theme. I just need to do some little improvements to distinguish between posts and pages when a vue-router link is clicked. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome. And I revised the answer a bit because I thought that extra info may help you and someone else. :)